# What do you call the "practical classes" that med students have at hospitals?

Tags: word-request

Maybe they are called *practices*? Example sentence:

> My practice at the hospital lasted forever. I arrived home around
>   midnight.

Comment: You should [probably avoid the specific word ***practice***, not least because *fully-qualified* doctors (community doctor = ***GP = General Practitioner*** in the UK) actually *work* in what's called a "practice" (rather than an "office", for example). And although you might *think* you want the tie-in between ***practice ... practical*** ("hands-on" as opposed to "theoretical" training), I think that would be a mistake in this exact context.

Comment: practicums is what they are called.

Comment: @Lambie: I didn't know that one (it's obviously domain-specific), but I stand by what I said as regards "ordinary" vocab. Incidentally, although OED says both plural forms are valid, [**practica** is far more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practica%2Cpracticums&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpractica%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpracticums%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What do you do during these "practices"?  Do you visit patients along with a doctor, make diagnoses, review charts, etc?  If so this is often referred to as "making the rounds" or simply "the rounds".

Comment: The question was what are these called? And I gave the answer.

Comment: @Lambie Actually you didn't answer. You made an unsupported comment that might be the starting point for an answer.

Comment: OED says ***practicum*** is primarily AmE, and can either refer to an *(extended) **course*** or a *(single) **session*** of practical training, ***esp. in teaching***. Checking Google Books for the sequence [have a practicum](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+a+practicum%22) it seems most of the usages are as a noun adjunct *(The training course will have a practicum component)*, or they refer to an extended period of "hands-on" work experience *(The APA required all accredited doctoral programs to have a practicum, which would be a one-year supervised experience)*.

Comment: Who cares what English it is? Anything wrong with AmE. Did anybody ask for BrE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Medical residents work very long **[shifts](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/to-your-health/wp/2017/03/10/first-year-doctors-will-be-allowed-to-work-24-hour-shifts-starting-in-july/?utm_term=.e36677df1c4e)**.

While on their shifts, they make **rounds**, visiting patients with their colleagues and a more experienced doctor.